# 2 jsp form saved into one SaveServlet

Tags: mysql, forms, jsp, servlets, netbeans-8

i made multiple steps form that the user needs to fill all of them

1st Form (personal details)

2nd Form (education details)

and both action pointed to one servlet which is SaveServlet

can any one of you help me on how to make the second servlet saved in the database? so far i tried only the first form managed to be saved in the database..

i also tried using one servlet for one form and both form were saved into the database but i dont know how to pass the id from the first form into the second form hence im trying to do multiple form in one servlet so that the id would be the same

Comment: please post your code...

Answer (score 0):

At the time of 1st Form submitted, do 3 things,

1) Persist data in DB.
2) Set attributes in session and redirect to same JSP.
3) Make a hidden input parameter in 2nd form with the value of ID from 1st form. data-attributes can also be used in this case.

Now you have ID from 1st form to be used when 2nd form is submitted.

I guess you can use ajax for handling multiple forms.

Comment: Shouldn't the front end handle the spreading of long form views? Its easier to collect all the data via the front end then submit all at once, than to try and submit everything little by little.

Comment: Agree to your point Derek. I could have explained more in my last line "Using Ajax".